# Safari IOS problem with encoding URI and json parsing

Tags: javascript, html, json, javascript-objects

```
var viewedthoughtsarr = {"viewed": [],"firstTime": false};
if (!(viewedthoughtsarr.firstTime)) {
  viewedthoughtsarr.firstTime = true;
  document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(viewedthoughtsarr));
  console.log(document.cookie);
  console.log(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(document.cookie)));
}
```

This is my code, I have used a ton of alerts to narrow down where the problem is. Basically, the problem is here:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(document.cookie)));
```

After this line of code, the rest of the script does not run, so the problem must be there. **But why?**

I encodedURI so that any commas or special characters do not affect the output when I receive data from MySQL database. It works completely fine on Chrome but on Safari IOS 13 it does not, unfortunately. I read that a Mac would help me track variables and understand where the problem is, but I don't have one.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! All I had to do was declare the cookie with a variable, such so:

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

and replaced all "document.cookie" statements in my code with x.